# Whenever invite button is clicked new form should be added everytime and when delete button clicked form gets deleted can anyone help me in this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, material-ui

**Invite.js**
this is my invite component in which invite button is outside of the form and delete button is inside of form.I want if delete button is click form should be deleted  In this I've used use state and I've have taken this form from material-ui help me if any one can how I can solve my problem ?

```
 import * as React from "react";
 import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
 import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
 import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
 import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
 import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
 import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
 import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
 import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

 const Invites = () => {

  const [ addForm,setAddForm]=React.useState(false)
 const [deleteForm, setdeleteForm]=React.useState(false)

  const setAddFormHandler = () => {
  console.log("clicked");
  setAddForm(true);
   };

  const deleteHandler=()=>{
   setdeleteForm(true)
  }

  return (
   <>
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="info"
      startIcon={<AddIcon />}
        onClick={setAddFormHandler}
    >
      ADD INVITE
    </Button>
     </Stack>

       {addForm ?<Box sx={{ "& > :not(style)": { m: 1 } }}>
       <FormControl>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
         
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
       
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
          
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
          
        />
      </Box>
      
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        spacing={4}
        style={{ marginLeft: 30, marginTop: 18, width: 500 }}
      >
        <Button variant="contained" size="large" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} onClick= 
     {deleteHandler}>
          Delete
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </FormControl>
    </Box>:null}
   </>
   );
   };
   export default Invites;
```

Comment: do you want like every time invite button is clicked, new forms should be added and each  form should have a delete button, onclick it should delete the respective form?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is confusing. So i'm adding two solutions here which addresses two perspectives of the problem, you can choose the one matching yours.

**Sol 1: You want to create new form for each click on invite button (multiple forms)**

The below solution will add new forms to the same page every time the invite button is clicked and delete the respective form once the delete button is clicked.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

const Invites = () => {

const [forms, setForm] = React.useState({ val: []});

function createcustomForms() {
    return forms.val.map((el, i) =>
      <div key={i}>
          <Box sx={{ "& > :not(style)": { m: 1 } }}>
       <FormControl>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
         
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
       
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
          
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 2 }}>
        <AccountCircle sx={{ color: "action.active", mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
        <TextField
          id="input-with-sx"
          label="With sx"
          variant="filled"
          
        />
      </Box>
      
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        spacing={4}
        style={{ marginLeft: 30, marginTop: 18, width: 500 }}
      >
        <Button variant="contained" size="large" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} 
        onClick={(e) => removeForm(i)}>
          Delete
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </FormControl>
    </Box>
      </div>
    );
  }

 const addForm = () => {
    setForm({ val: [...forms.val, '']})    
  }

 const removeForm = (i) => {
    let vals = [...forms.val];
    vals.splice(i,1);
    setForm({ val: vals });   
  }
  
 return (
  <>
   <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="info"
      startIcon={<AddIcon />}
        onClick={addForm}
    >
      ADD INVITE
    </Button>
     </Stack>
   {createcustomForms()}
     
  </>
  );
  };
  export default Invites;
```

**Sol 2 : You want to create a form when invite button is clicked and delete it when delete button is clicked (currently in your code delete is not working)**

```
const deleteHandler=()=>{
   setdeleteForm(true)
  }
```

should be changed to

```
 const deleteHandler=()=>{
      setAddForm(false);
      }
```